# main thread stopping and waiting for backround thread to finish before continuing

Tags: c#

I am trying to make a simple application that counts the amount of songs I have in a separate class from my main class and while it is counting it update my label. So I broke off my music getmusic method into a different object. For some reason my main thread does not continue working when I create my second thread. Any help would be appreciated I'm new to programming so if there is a better way to do it that is more efficient I would be glad to listen to any suggestions.

```
private void btnGetMusic_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        getMus.GetMusic();
        System.Threading.Thread MusThread = new System.Threading.Thread(getMus.GetMusic);
        MusThread.IsBackground = true;
        MusThread.Start();
        while (true)
        {
            lblNumberOfSongs.Text = getMus.holder.Count.ToString();
        }


    }
```

Comment: You're blocking the UI thread forever with your while loop, thus preventing it from ever doing anything ever again, freezing your application.  Don't block the UI thread.

Comment: What is the purpose of the `while(true)` loop?  It's going to freeze your UI since it's part of the main thread.

Comment: Sure sounds like the `while` loop should be on its own thread. Also; it will need to use the `Dispatcher` to update the UI.

Comment: Use a BackgroundWorker and ReportProgress. It's simpler than wrangling your own threads.

Comment: This code example doesn't sense to me. You call the `GetMusic()` method, then you start a thread which will also call it? I see 2 possibilities here, neither of which necessarily use `BackgroundWorker`: simply define an event on the `getMus` or `getMus.holder` object's type, which is raised when the `getMus.holder.Count` property changes; or change the `getMus` object design so that you can iterate on the elements retrieved and then use `async`/`await` in a loop doing that iteration to update the UI. With a good code example, you can get better advice. http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As people above commented, your while loop is not taking place inside the background thread, it is taking place inside the main UI thread. Only the method that you pass to the new instance of the thread (in this case getMus.GetMusic) is run in the background thread. Therefore, since the while loop is just going to run forever since you said while(true), this is what is blocking your UI from responding, not the background thread.

If you want to continuously update your label while the background thread is running, try a join statement with a timeout. Also, you are calling GetMusic once and then immediately calling it again in the background thread, is that duplication needed? You could try this:

```
private void btnGetMusic_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    System.Threading.Thread MusThread = new System.Threading.Thread(getMus.GetMusic);
    MusThread.IsBackground = true;
    MusThread.Start();

    //this waits timeout # of milliseconds for the thread to be done
    //if thread not done, update the label
    //if thread done, exits while loop
    while (!MusThread.Join(timeout))
    {
        lblNumberOfSongs.Text = getMus.holder.Count.ToString();
    }


}
```

That would still hang your UI while it waited for the background thread to be completely done, but it wouldn't hang forever unless the background thread actually ran forever.

A better way would be to get rid of the whole while loop, and instead have a timer on your main UI form, set it to a certain timeout, and enable it just before you start the thread, then in the timer tick event code, you update the label and then check if MusThread.IsAlive and disable the timer if not. This way your UI doesn't hang at all. You would need to move the declaration of MusThread to be a class field rather than inside the btnGetMusic_Click method, or it would be out of scope and inaccessible.

As a further alternative, I can also suggest that you may not need to use a separate thread for a simple count of songs. I generally only use threads when the task is very large in scope, complexity, and/or latency, thus potentially substantially slowing down the responsiveness of the UI.

Now, I don't know how many songs you are talking about, perhaps you have billions, and you don't want your UI to hang while you wait for it to count them all. But a better implementation than recounting each time, if you can manage it, is to keep a running total of songs as they get added or subtracted to your class. Then the count function is just returning the running total, a single integer; essentially instantaneous and not requiring the hassle and headache of threads. You'll likely not notice the overhead of an increment or decrement statement per every song addition or removal.

Comment: `Thread.Join` blocks the calling thread. This will freeze the UI until the background thread completes. One step up from freezing it *forever* as per the OP's code, but you won't see updates as the thread runs.. (actually you mention this after the code block, but before it you say "If you want to continuously update your label while the background thread is running, try a join statement with a timeout" .. so .. not sure what the point of that code block is :P)

Comment: It is join with a timeout, you make the timeout really small, and it only blocks for a couple milliseconds or whatever, updates the label, then tries again. It is true that the UI will effectively be frozen. I did say it wasn't the optimal solution. I would use the timer option probably.

Comment: It wont ever update the label. The ui thread is always either blocking or running your code. You could add a call to Application. DoEvents and it would do what you describe.